# Bash script suddenly stops working after an hour

Tags: bash, vpn

I have a `bash` script which I really cannot get to work. The script should first and foremost change *VPN* every *X*-minutes, and then also, if my connection drops, shift *VPN*. The script can be seen below:

```
re='^[0-9]+$'

sudo rm -rf /tmp/All_IPs_this_boot
sudo -u frederik touch /tmp/All_IPs_this_boot

while :
do
    # Restart the VPN, however, only if skype is not running!
    if ! [[ $(pidof skype) =~ $re ]] ; then
        sudo bash 'restart-vpn.sh' &
    else
        echo "Error: Skype is running"
    fi

    # Generate random overall sleep time before restart is forced
    TimesOverall=$(shuf -i 35-65 -n 1)
    echo "Times to check: $TimesOverall"    

    # Will check whether the restart worked
    n=1
    while [[ $n -le $TimesOverall ]]; do
        # Choose "random" website to ping
        rand=$(shuf -i1-5 -n1)
        if [ $rand == 1 ]; then
            Website=$(echo "duckduckgo.com")
        elif [ $rand == 2 ]; then
            Website=$(echo "pingmyurl.com")
        elif [ $rand == 3 ]; then
            Website=$(echo "ping.eu")
        elif [ $rand == 4 ]; then
            Website=$(echo "lenovo.com")
        else
            Website=$(echo "archlinux.org")
        fi

        if [[ $(ping -4 -c 3 $Website | \
                sed '1d' | sed -n 1,4p | cut -c1-14 | \
                awk '{printf("%s", $0 (NR==1 ? "" : ""))}') \
              == "64 bytes from 64 bytes from 64 bytes from " ]]
        then
            { echo -e "IP is $(cat /tmp/ip) at $(date '+%d-%m %H:%M:%S')"; \
              cat "/tmp/All_IPs_this_boot"; } > "/tmp/All_IPs_this_boot.new"
            mv "/tmp/All_IPs_this_boot.new" "/tmp/All_IPs_this_boot"        
            sleep 20
            ((n++))
        else
            sleep 6

            # Choose "random" website to ping
            rand=$(shuf -i1-5 -n1)
            if [ $rand == 1 ]; then
                Website=$(echo "duckduckgo.com")
            elif [ $rand == 2 ]; then
                Website=$(echo "pingmyurl.com")
            elif [ $rand == 3 ]; then
                Website=$(echo "ping.eu")
            elif [ $rand == 4 ]; then
                Website=$(echo "lenovo.com")
            else
                Website=$(echo "archlinux.org")
            fi

            if [[ $(ping -4 -c 4 $Website | 
                    sed '1d' | sed -n 1,4p | cut -c1-14 | \
                    awk '{printf("%s", $0 (NR==1 ? "" : ""))}') \
                  == "64 bytes from 64 bytes from 64 bytes from 64 bytes from " ]]
            then
                { echo -e "IP is $(cat /tmp/ip) at $(date '+%d-%m %H:%M:%S')"; \
                  cat "/tmp/All_IPs_this_boot"; } > "/tmp/All_IPs_this_boot.new"
                mv "/tmp/All_IPs_this_boot.new" "/tmp/All_IPs_this_boot"                    
                sleep 20
                ((n++))
            else
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

The problem with the script is that it works properly for like an hour or so, then suddenly, which I can see in the file */tmp/All_IPs_this_boot*, it stops working - it does not write anything to */tmp/All_IPs_this_boot*. Furthermore, I can see that the process is running, so it is not because it is not running, the script just doesn't work after an hour, and I have to manually restart my *VPN*.

Comment: Try `set -o xtrace` in the script or `ps wafux` on the shell to see what's executing when it fails.

Comment: Is it possible that the `sudo` commands are throwing permissions out or even timing out? Is it possible to re-write those section of the script and test?

Comment: This script is *absurdly, horrifyingly* complex.  Please, please, please, before you write any more scripts, read the [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Comment: for instance `Website=$(echo "duckduckgo.com")` can be replaced by `Website=duckduck.go`, `if .. elif ... elif ...` by `switch` unless you like complex script that is.

Comment: @Archemar, no such thing as `switch` in Bash.  Perhaps you meant `case`?  Agree with your point about `Website=...`.

Comment: @Wildcard yes `case ...esac` . I use this operation more in php/C than bash ...

Comment: Thank you for the great feedback! 

I have followed what you have said and has therefore been able to simplify the script. Furthermore, I found the solution to my script: the problem was the ping command, when I use curl to retrieve a given website, instead of using ping to test the internet connection, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

This entire script could be productively replaced by adding the *single* line below to root's crontab:

```
* * * * * pidof skype >/dev/null 2>&1 || /path/to/restart-vpn.sh
```

The specified command will be run every minute.

Specifically, every minute, if the `skype` process isn't running, the `restart-vpn.sh` script will be run.

The contents of that `restart-vpn.sh` script probably should be consolidated to a single line as well.

Also, it *probably* doesn't need root permissions.

---

By the way, it seems that you are using the `/tmp/ip` file and the `/tmp/All_IPs_this_boot` file as a sort of "magic interface" between the script shown above and the `restart-vpn.sh` script.  Please learn to pass command line arguments instead.

---

The easiest way to see what a shell script is doing is to add `set -x` at the top and then run it.

Comment: Thank you for the great help!

The reason I am using /tmp/ip is because I find it convenient when I want to know my IP in different scripts - for example when I want conky to show my current IP.

The reason I am using /tmp/All_IPs_this_boots is because I wanted to troubleshoot, however, that is not necessary any more, because I found the solution, which was to use curl instead of ping to test my internet connection.

It, unfortunately, needs root permission, because I use OpenVPN.